# Renaming classes in XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml

Consider the following C# code:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class A 
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<B> ArrayOfBItems { get;set; }

}

public class B
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Name { get;set; }
}
```

When run through XmlSerialzier, will produce the following:

```
<A>
    <B Name="Foo" />
    <B Name="Bar" />
</A>
```

What can I do, short of renaming class B to change the name that is output in XML?  Adding XmlAttribute to a class is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot]
public class A 
{
    [XmlElement("NewName")]
    public List<B> ArrayOfBItems { get;set; }

}
```

If you change the xml decoration from XmlArray to XmlElement, you should get your expected result.